# Dynamic VBA macro to hide all pivot table values

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a dynamic and quick way to hide all pivot table values. As of now, I have the code below, but this only works as long as there aren't any new values (Example: if account "333" was added to the data, the script would break). Any suggestions?

```
Sub Hide_Accounts()
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Account")
       .PivotItems("000").Visible = False
       .PivotItems("111").Visible = False
       .PivotItems("222").Visible = False
       .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't hide all the items in a field (that would raise an error). An alternative is to hide the whole field.

Try this code and read the comments to adjust it to your needs:

```
Sub Hide_Accounts()

    Dim evalPivotTable As PivotTable
    Dim evalPivotField As pivotField

    Dim targetSheetName As String
    Dim targetPivotTableName As String
    Dim targetPivotFieldName As String

    ' Define the names of sheet and pivot table
    targetSheetName = "Sheet1"
    targetPivotTableName = "PivotTable2"
    targetPivotFieldName = "Account"

    Set evalPivotTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(targetSheetName).PivotTables(targetPivotTableName)

    ' Loop through all pivot table fields
    For Each evalPivotField In evalPivotTable.PivotFields

        If evalPivotField.Name = targetPivotFieldName And evalPivotField.Orientation <> xlHidden Then
            ' Hide the field
            evalPivotField.Orientation = xlHidden

            ' You can exit the loop because you have hidden the entire field
            Exit For

        End If

    Next evalPivotField

End Sub
```

Remember to mark the answer if it helped you to help others.

Comment: Maybe you may use .ShowDetail property. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600980/collapsing-pivotfield-with-duplicate-occurence-name)